# How can my PC composite ultra-high dimension images with Blender?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, system, resolution

To be more specific, I'm on a machine which can easily go through 1080p images in at worst about 20 seconds, unless I'm doing something weird and cool with it. So this isn't a low-end machine per se. However, if I'm attempting to produce something 24"×36" poster print ready at 300 DPI, the recommendation is 10800x7200 pixels, which, even for an image which generally takes about six seconds per frame for an animation, has been crashing my machine.

To clarify, I'm using Cycles and can't easily compromise on that. The crash usually happens at compositing, in which I'm applying a few filters (inclusive of denoise, glare, and sun beams, but I feel this is beside the bigger problem). They're kind of essential to the flavor of the final image, so I'm not necessarily ready to drop them just yet. Getting to that final point of composition takes roughly two hours on CPU rendering and generally runs without any significant hitches, taking up only half a gig of RAM.

Compositing gobbles up all of the RAM, ruthlessly.

My workaround has been to render at a lower resolution, and scale it up, which is all kinds of a problem for me in general principle. So, it's not really a solution so much as a shim.

I have 16 GB of DDR5, high speed but kind of the low end, and would consider just getting more RAM, but given that Cycles is a ray tracer capable of tiling, I'm wondering if it's possible to render and composite portions of the image at a time? (Additionally, I have no idea how much memory it wants to reserve, and may not be able to get enough for some images.) Can I have it render part of the image to its own file, and perhaps composite afterward in some limited way? The end .exr in the temp directory is roughly 3.0 GB.

I feel like I might be overlooking an easier solution.

Comment: I wonder if rendering to exr and compositing as a second step afterwards would improve this any

Comment: You would at least be saving the render payload when it crashes :p

Comment: @AllenSimpson I tried that with the exr saved in tmp; incidentally, while not a bad idea, it didn't help.